# Che cosa vuol dire "magro" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nell'[articolo di Wikipedia sugli agnolotti piemontesi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnolotti_piemontesi) ho letto:

> La ricetta classica non prevede la creazione di agnolotti piemontesi di **magro**: nel raro caso vengano prodotti, sono comunque denominati ravioli; allo stesso modo sono denominati ravioli gli agnolotti piemontesi contenenti un ripieno a base di fontina, comuni nel Canavese e nella Valle d'Aosta.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "magro" in questa frase? Leggendo la voce "magro" in parecchi dizionari ho pensato che si riferisse a un ripieno di carne magra. Ricercando su Google, però, ho visto alcune ricette di "ravioli di magro" che non contengono carne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L’espressione “di magro” fa riferimento alla ritualità della Chiesa  Cattolica riguardo il cibo che si può consumare durante determinati periodi. Il seguente pezzo fa riferimento ai tortellini, ma il discorso vale per ogni tipo di pietanza:

> Tradizionalmente sono considerati [un piatto di magro](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortelli_alla_piacentina), ***cioè quelli privi di carne il cui consumo era concesso dalla Chiesa cattolica nei giorni di venerdì, durante la Quaresima o alla vigilia delle principali festività cristiane.***

[L'astinenza dalle carni:](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astinenza_dalle_carni)

> è un precetto generale della Chiesa cattolica che impone di non mangiare carne nei ***"giorni di magro"*** , ossia il venerdì e gli altri giorni proibiti. Il pesce è ammesso durante l'astinenza, ragion per cui il venerdì è il giorno in cui tradizionalmente si consuma pesce nei paesi a maggioranza cattolica.